# Axios resolves promise even though the request was canceled with React.StrictMode

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, axios

I am using axios in my react project. React.StrictMode is enabled by default, so components get rendered twice. I am aware of this behavior and i have set up an abort control for my axios instance, and i do call its `abort()` method in the useEffect clean up function. The problem is my callback function for the request's success in the `.then` statement still gets called with an undefined response, and the `.catch` clause is never really triggered and i don't know why.

here's my code for fetching the data:

```
useEffect(
   
 () => {
      setIsLoading(true);
      const { request, cancel } = httpService.retrieve(id);
      request
        .then((resp) =>
 {
          console.log("response", resp);

          // setData(resp.data);
          setIsLoading(false);
        })
        .catch((error) => {
          if (error instanceof CanceledError) return;
          setIsLoading(false);
          setError(error.message);
        });

      return () => cancel();
    },
    []
  );
```

and here's my axios instance configuration

```
 retrieve<T>(id: string) {
    const controller = new AbortController();
    const request = this.apiClient.get<T>(`${this.endpoint}/${id}/`, {
      signal: controller.signal,
    });

    return { request, cancel: () => controller.abort() };
  }
```

it might also be useful to mention that i have a resaponse and a request interceptors for my axios instance, i don't know if these are causing the problem. Here's their implementation:

```
 useEffect(() => {
    const requestInterceptor = apiClient.interceptors.request.use(
      (config) => {
        console.log(config);

        if (!config.headers.Authorization)
          config.headers.Authorization = `Bearer ${auth.access}`;
        return config;
      },
      (error) => Promise.reject(error)
    );

    const responseInterceptor = apiClient.interceptors.response.use(
      (response) => response,
      async (error) => {
        const prevRequest = error?.config;
        if (error?.response?.status === 401 && !prevRequest?.sent) {
          if (prevRequest) {
            prevRequest.sent = true;
            const access = await getToken();
            prevRequest.headers.Authorization = `Bearer ${access}`;
            return apiClient(prevRequest);
          }
          return Promise.reject(error);
        }
      }
    );
    return () => {
      apiClient.interceptors.request.eject(requestInterceptor);
      apiClient.interceptors.response.eject(responseInterceptor);
    };
  }, [auth]);
```

finally here is the output when i console log inside of the `.then` handler
[image]

i tried putting a `console.log` inside of my `cancel` method and it does get called, i am not sure how to check if axios is actually canceling the request or something is preventing it.

Answer (score 0):

Okay my fault, I just had to move the return `Promise.reject(error)` from inside of the if statement to the body of the function, in the response interceptor.